# How to insert/remove rows from Poco::Data::RecordSet based on list

Tags: poco-libraries

Im trying to use Poco::Data::RecordSet with internal storage type std::list, as explained here:
http://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html
select << "SELECT * FROM Person", list, now; // use std::list as internal storage container

I want to do this as I need to insert/delete rows to/from the recordset after retrieval.

Bu how do I remove or insert a row into the record set when the internal storage is list.
Can't find any documentation for how to do this.
The Poco::Data::RecordSet does not seem to have any removeRow() or insertRow() like members.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way currently to do that - you can filter unwanted data through either query clause or create a [RowFilter](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.RowFilter.html) for the RecordSet. Alternatively, you can copy it to another container, but there's obviously performance penalty associated with that.

If you would like to see the feature in a future release, either submit a feature request on github or send a pull request.